# Codename One local notification doesn't show up on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I followed [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html) blog to implement local notifications for an app and the block of code from it is the following:

```
LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
n.setId("demo-notification");
n.setAlertBody("It's time to take a break and look at me");
n.setAlertTitle("Break Time!");
// n.setAlertSound("/notification_sound_beep-01a.mp3");
    // alert sound file name must begin with notification_sound

Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
        n,
        System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000, // fire date/time
        LocalNotification.REPEAT_MINUTE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
);
```

It shows up just fine on iOS but not on my Android 13 device

Comment: Is your app in the foreground? Try minimizing the app before the firing to see if the notification will show.

Comment: No, the app was minimized. Notifications showed as expected on an Android 9 device but not with Android 13. Permissions have been allowed so not sure why this is happening

Comment: This might be something we need to look into.